# How can I make a macro to run a few PowerShell commands one after the other?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I am using Amazon Web Service Powershell extension. I have multiple commands I want to run after each other like this:

```
PS C:\g> Write-S3Object -BucketName "user-staging" -Key "index.html" -File "index.html"
PS C:\g> Write-S3Object -BucketName 'user-staging' -KeyPrefix 'lib/pagedown' -Folder 'lib/pagedown' -SearchPattern '*.js'
```

How can I combine these into a macro, batch file or something similar so I can run them all just with one simple command such as:

```
PS C:\g> publish-files
```

Comment: Put them together in a batch file and make an alias for running them.

Comment: TJ - can you explain more. I did try putting it all into an abc.bat file but then when I tried to run it from within powershell I think I recall it gave some strange errors. At the time I thought I was doing it wrong.

Comment: What were the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a PowerShell script file. Basically the same as a batch file, but with a .ps1 extension.

Comment: Thanks - I actually tried a .ps file but not .ps1.  Glad you could help.